# Generate thumbnail using BufferedImage without inverting color and gain alpha in Java

Tags: java, graphics

I using 'BufferedImage' to generate thumbnail by this code.

```
try {
 BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(thumWidth, thumHeight, TYPE_INT_ARGB);
 Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();

 Image ii = (new ImageIcon(orgFile.getAbsolutePath())).getImage();

 g.drawImage(ii, 0, 0, thumWidth, thumHeight, null);
 String thumbFileDir = prefixPath + "/" + thumWidth + "/" + afterPath;
 File file = this.createPathIfnotexist(thumbFileDir);
 String fullPathToSave = this.genPath(file.getAbsolutePath(), fileName);
 File thumbFile = new File(fullPathToSave);
 ImageIO.write(bi, ext, thumbFile);
} catch (IOException var22) {
 var22.printStackTrace();
 return;
} catch (Exception var23) {
 var23.printStackTrace();
}
```

My problem is...

1. When i get instance of BufferedImage with `TYPE_INT_RGB`, lose alpha when sending PNG file and it's fine when sending JPG file. [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9XMC.jpg), [Converted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR0ih.jpg)
2. When i get instance of BufferedImage with `TYPE_INT_ARGB`, gain alpha when sending PNG file but color is inverse when sending JPG file. [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqSbT.jpg), [Converted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o5Rs.jpg)

So, i want create thumbnail without inverting color and maintain alpha. How can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a result of my continued research, I thought it would be more convenient to **use an external library** than to try it out in the way suggested in the question.

So, I decided to **use [java-image-scaling](https://github.com/mortennobel/java-image-scaling) to generate the thumbnail.**

For those who visit this page in the future, I leave some code. (Actually, the question was written in Java, but the answer is written in Kotlin.)

`imgLocation` is uploaded path of origin image, `width` is reference point such as 100, 240, 480, 720, 1080.

```
    private val rootLocation: Path by lazy { Paths.get(location) }
    private val formatNames = ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames().toList()

    override fun resizeImage(imgLocation: String, width: Int): File {
        val originFile = this.rootLocation.resolve(imgLocation).toFile()
        val destFile = this.rootLocation.resolve("resized-$width-${originFile.name}").toFile()

        val bufferedImage: BufferedImage = originFile.inputStream().use { ImageIO.read(it) }
        val resizeImage = if (width <= bufferedImage.width) {
            val nHeight = width * bufferedImage.height / bufferedImage.width
            val rescale = MultiStepRescaleOp(width, nHeight).apply { unsharpenMask = AdvancedResizeOp.UnsharpenMask.Soft }
            rescale.filter(bufferedImage, null)
        } else {
            bufferedImage
        }

        val target = if (formatNames.contains(destFile.extension)) destFile else File(destFile.path + ".jpg")
        ImageIO.write(resizeImage, target.extension, target)

        bufferedImage.flush()
        return destFile
    }
```